# Moose attribute exists

Tags: perl, introspection, moose

I am attempting to iterate over the attributes of a Moose object, printing the value of attributes without invoking any lazy builders (though printing if the attribute value exists).

My code so far looks like:

```
for my $attr ($object->meta->get_all_attributes) {
    my $name = $attr->name;

    # Lazy attributes that have not already been generated will not
    # exist in the object hash.
    next unless exists $object->{$name}

    my $value = $object->$name;
    print $value;
}
```

Is there a way of inspecting the object using Moose that will tell me if the attribute value exists, without modifying the Moose class itself?

i.e. a more elegant alternative to the "next unless exists" line in the code above

Thanks for any help and consideration :)

Answer (score 4):

Reading the [Moose::Meta::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose%3a%3aMeta%3a%3aClass) documentation will point you to [Class::MOP::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class%3a%3aMOP%3a%3aClass) and [Class::MOP::Attribute](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class%3a%3aMOP%3a%3aAttribute).

You can then write code something like this:

```
foreach my $attr ($object->meta->get_all_attributes) {
  my $name = $attr->name;

  next unless $attr->has_value($object);

  # Or, perhaps get_value(), depending on your requirements.
  say $attr->get_raw_value($object);
}
```